# Couchdb authentication using second server

Tags: authentication, couchdb, pouchdb

Detailed information seems to be hard to find on this. So the situation I have is an existing server with usernames and passwords. I'm adding an additional couchdb server to manage data for a mobile app, however I still want all authentication to be handled via the existing server.
So I can send an HTTP request with username and password to the existing server and i can get it to send back anyanything i like  if access is accepted. How could I then use that information to authenticate with the couchdb server?
I imagine it would be possible to recieve a secret from the existing server on successful authentication that we could match to one we have manually stored on couchdb server. However that doesn't seem to be very secure.

I have read the Authentication docs at couchdb but I'm still confused. Any suggestions for an authentication system?

Comment: One solution could be to use a proxy or a layer on top of your access to the CouchDB servers. This would be slower but authentification handling would be centralized.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have the expertise to set that up, but it could be an option for the future. I'm just really struggling to understand Proxy Authentication in couchDb. Is it supposed to give you session access like the cookie authentication API?

Comment: Basically I want it exactly like this, but with CouchDB. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth

Answer (score 0):

I think JWT authentication is what you're looking for. There's a plugin which can do this for you: https://github.com/dmunch/couch_jwt_auth (The repository is a fork, implementing additional functionality to the original one plus is compatible with CouchDB 2.0.)

Basically you send your username/password to the authentication server, which in turn gives you back a token (the JWT). You can now authenticate to CouchDB using this token. CouchDB verifies the integrity of the token either by using a shared secret (HS256) or by using the public key of the authentication server.

Comment: Thanks that does look like what I needed. However, I did manage to get CouchDB Proxy Authentication working by sending the username and shared secret - encoded via HMAC-SHA1 - from the authentication server to couchDB. I managed to do this in couchdb 1.6.1 but in 2.0 it seems like its broken.